# how to change mime types in MAMP

Tags: apache, html, apache2, mamp

I'm developing a website that has a HTML5 video. It looks like when ogg files are served with other mime types than video/ogg firefox flips. I've updated the mime.types file inside the mamp/apache/config folder and have restarted the MAMP server multiple times, but ogg files are still served with plain/text context-type.

Can someone point out what I need to do?

UPDATE

The only time I'm able to change the mime type is if I change the `DefaultType text/plain` to `DefaultType video/ogg` which is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `mod_mime_magic` installed and enabled?  Is your mime magic working correctly?  When you do `file -m` on one of your OGG files, does it say it is a plain text file?  Are the file extensions correct?

Comment: i ran test-video-ogg.ogv -m but it failed. I also found this in my config file. <IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>MIMEMagicFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/magic</IfModule>. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Try running `file -i -m /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/magic test-video-ogg.ogv`.  If that doesn't report `video/ogg`, your problem is the magic file.

Comment: can you please point me to some place where I can read on how to edit the magic file?

Comment: @Am: Updating the magic file isn't something you should attempt to do manually.  But now that we've found *why* this is failing, you can fix it by adding `ForceType video/ogg .ogv` to either an htaccess file or an applicable `Directory` or `Location` directive in your Apache config.

Answer (score 8):

The mime.types file is in Applications/MAMP/conf/apache

There you can alter your mime types.
Reset server after changing the file for it to take effect.

Comment: The exact entry you should make is... "application/wasm     wasm". Then as stated, restart MAMP and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Adding mime-type is the same for all, it's just you need to understand how the types will be applied and what's the mime-type point is. In this answer I'll how I tried to add WebAssembly mime-type `application/wasm` in MAMP.

Here it goes:

I recently tried **WebAssembly in MAMP** and configured out the below mime-type that works for me.

First, we need to navigate the folder of `MAMP` in MacOS's `Applications/MAMP/conf/apache`, And then open the file `mime.types` in any editor.

After opening the file, add the following line anywhere in the `mime.types` file:

```
application/wasm wasm
```

Here is the example wasm mime type in my `mime.types` file:

```
#application/wasm
application/wasm wasm
```

Answer (score 0):

In MAMP Pro these days you can add `<VirtualHost>` parameters using the gui. Here's a screenshot showing how I add MIME types for .mjs and .wasm as:

```
AddType application/javascript      .mjs
AddType application/wasm      wasm
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3o2F.png)

Don't forget to restart the server after adding.