# Google Chrome gives warning Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:

Tags: google-chrome, playframework-2.0

I keep getting this warning

Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff".

I am using Play 2.0.4 webserver. I added the mime-types to my application.conf file as follows

```
mimetype.eot = application/vnd.ms-fontobject
mimetype.otf = application/octet-stream
mimetype.ttf=application/x-font-ttf
mimetype.woff = application/x-font-woff
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: Me too. What's up with that.

Comment: Guarav, please select my answer when you get a chance. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer:

> Some browsers, like Google Chrome, will show this warning when a font
>   is downloaded from a web server that sets an unexpected MIME type for
>   fonts.
>
> For many font types, there is a solution!
>
> Update the configuration for your web server with the following MIME
>   type per font file extension:
>
> ```
> .ttf — font/truetype 
> .otf — font/opentype 
> .eot — application/vnd.ms-fontobject 
> .woff — application/x-font-woff
> ```
>
> If you
>   are using Apache configuration, you may include the AddType directive
>   for each font type:
>
> AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
>     AddType font/truetype ttf
>     AddType application/x-font-woff woff
>     AddType font/opentype otf
>
> With a specific MIME type configured per font, and not the generic
>   application/octet-stream MIME type, you should no longer see a warning
>   in your web browser console.
>
> This configuration — while effective for cleaning up your console —
>   does not include the technically correct MIME type for fonts like OTF,
>   TTF, and WOFF. For these font types, an official MIME type has not
>   (yet) been approved. An official type for WOFF — application/font-woff
>   — has been requested.AddType font/opentype otf

http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/resource-interpreted-font-transferred-mime-type

Comment: I'm using MAMP and have this same problem with fontawesome woff font. I added "application/x-font-woff    woff" to my MAMP/conf/apache/mime.types file, and "AddType application/x-font-woff  woff" to my MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf file, but still have the warning coming up in Chrome... Not sure about what to do with the magic file as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3226777/1362009 ?

Comment: @RayOnAir Adding this to .htaccess in MAMP works for me - the docs say that the addType directive can be used in the following contexts: server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

Comment: According to [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b) application/font-woff is now officially recommended.

Comment: application/font-woff worked for me in MAMP Pro when the others did not.  Thank you marshall

Answer (score 4):

For my IIS instance, i had to use the following:

`.woff` — `application/font-woff` (not `application/x-font-woff`)

See:

- [Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/x-font-woff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704967/resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-x-font-w)
- http://zduck.com/2013/google-chrome-and-woff-font-mime-type-warnings/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Rack-based app, you can amend the `Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES` hash in your `config.ru`:

```
# Additional mime types
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({
  ".eot" => "application/vnd.ms-fontobject",
  ".ttf" => "font/ttf",
  ".otf" => "font/otf",
  ".woff" => "application/x-font-woff"
})
```