# Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/x-font-woff

Tags: qooxdoo

I followed the [Web Fonts tutorial](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.5/pages/gui_toolkit/ui_webfonts.html) in qooxdoo documentation to add a web font to Font.js , but I notice there is a warning in Chrome's Developer Console:

My code is as follow:

```
/* ************************************************************************
  #asset(myApp/fonts/*)
************************************************************************ */
qx.Theme.define("myApp.theme.Font",
{
  extend : qx.theme.simple.Font,

  fonts :
  {
    "silkscreen" :
    {
        size: 8,
        lineHeight: 1,
        family: [ "silkscreen", "Tahoma" ],
        sources:
        [
            {
                family: "Silkscreen",
                source:
                [
                    "myApp/fonts/slkscr-webfont.eot",
                    "myApp/fonts/slkscr-webfont.ttf",
                    "myApp/fonts/slkscr-webfont.woff",
                    "myApp/fonts/slkscr-webfont.svg#silkscreen"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  }
});
```

How can I resolve the browser warning ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

According to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b), the correct MIME type is `application/font-woff`, so you need to configure your web server to use that when serving .woff files.

Comment: It works. After I added the line `AddType application/font-woff .woff` in `httpd.conf` of my Apache server's config (then restart server), the warning disappears.

Comment: Tried this solution, the issue persists. This is in a dev environment using EasyPHP.

Comment: Is the default value set by the Apache foundation? Can we get them to update it?

Comment: Update: I submitted a bug report to the Apache foundation. Hopefully they'll update the default value in a future release.

Comment: The following rules worked for me:

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/font-woff .woff

Comment: @iamdash, thanks for posting your conf relating to other font types. But doesn't the 2nd directive for .woff simply override the 1st? IOW, I think you're only really setting .woff to application/font-woff and the next-to-last directive ("AddType application/x-font-woff .woff") is never applied. I think for .woff in particular, Daniel Wagner's answer remains correct.

PS I used to see this console error, but in latest Chrome (29.0.1547.65, on OSX) my .woff font has type application/x-font-woff and does not trigger console errors. Maybe Chrome is suppressing the error now? /$.02

Answer (score 85):

If you are using an IIS webserver, give this a try:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the meaning of accepted answer, if the web server is in IIS. no need the `#` marks, right?